# In a method of a C# managed class, how to pass an instance of a C++ class?

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed

I'm working on a joint project where there's a need to wrap a C++ DLL and refer to it from C#.

I'm not from a Microsoft technology background so I do apologise if my terminology is incorrect or this ends up being a straightforward response or one that's already answered - but I certainly cannot find that answer despite a good search.

So far, work has been done by the other party to convert the DLL in question to a managed one. This has allowed me to include it as a reference in my C# project (I'm using VS 2017). The other party has also sent me a C# example (only one method 'Clear' implemented) of how to provide a wrapper, as follows:

```
#pragma once
#include "cgcl.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace ThirdParty_DOPRL;

namespace ThirdParty_GCL 
  {
    public ref class CGCL_MAN
      {
        public:
            // Allocate the native object on the C++ Heap via a constructor
            CGCL_MAN() : m_pGCL( new CGCL ) {}

            // Deallocate the native object on a destructor
            ~CGCL_MAN() {
              delete m_pGCL;
            }

        protected:
            // Deallocate the native object on the finalizer just in case no destructor is called
            !CGCL_MAN() {
                delete m_pGCL;
            }

        public:
            void Clear() {
                return m_pGCL->Clear();
            }

        private:
            CGCL * m_pGCL;
      };
  }
```

All builds OK and working so far (i.e. a call to Clear() from C# appears to execute).

I now want to add the stub for another method from the same unmanaged class as above. Its signature in the original header file is as follows:

```
  STATUS GetListOfDevProperties(CDeviceObjectPropertyReferenceList &DevicePropertyList) const;
```

So the first thing I did was to create another wrapper class around the unmanaged class CDeviceObjectPropertyReferenceList, as follows:

```
#pragma once

#include "cdoprl.h"

using namespace System;

namespace ThirdParty_DOPRL
{
    public ref class CDOPRL_MAN
    {
    public:
        // Allocate the native object on the C++ Heap via a constructor
        CDOPRL_MAN() : m_pDevObjPropRefList(new CDeviceObjectPropertyReferenceList) {}

        // Deallocate the native object on a destructor
        ~CDOPRL_MAN() {
            delete m_pDevObjPropRefList;
        }

    protected:
        // Deallocate the native object on the finalizer just in case no destructor is called
        !CDOPRL_MAN() {
            delete m_pDevObjPropRefList;
        }

    public:
        bool IsEmpty() {
            return m_pDevObjPropRefList->empty();
        }

        void Clear() {
            return m_pDevObjPropRefList->clear();
        }

        size_t Size() {
            return m_pDevObjPropRefList->size();
        }

    private:
        CDeviceObjectPropertyReferenceList * m_pDevObjPropRefList;
    };
}
```

Returning now to ThirdParty_GCL (at the top of this post), I assumed I must use managed class types in the stub, and declared the stub as follows:

```
            STATUS GetListOfDevProperties(CDOPRL_MAN devPropList) {
                return m_pGCL->GetListOfDevProperties(devPropList);
            }
```

However, of course, VS warns me that the mention of devPropList in the above return statement is invalid ("a simple non-tracking reference cannot be bound to an entity on the managed heap") - which to me, in simple terms, means I am illegally mixing references to unmanaged and managed classes.

In short, is there any way of converting between the managed CDOPRL_MAN class type and the unmanaged CDeviceObjectPropertyReferenceList class type required by the original C++ DLL ?

Hope I've provided enough info.

Comment: Are you missing the Ampersand?  It is in the first example and not in second.

Comment: Thanks, but no joy. Not being adept at C++, I tried all combinations of prefixing the parameter both in the declaration and the return statement - all of them VS marks as invalid.

Comment: I think the issue is where the variable is located.  The variable cannot be on the c++ execution stack (on a parameter list or return object).  The variable has to be in Global Memory.  This article may halp : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-use-tracking-references-in-cpp-cli?view=vs-2019